# Cant get ngx-restangular working on ionic 4 project getting Error: Cannot find module "core-js/fn/object"

Tags: ngx-restangular

Cant get restangular working on ionic 4 project getting

```
Error: Cannot find module "core-js/fn/object"
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/vendor.js:140769:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.364 (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/main.js:7`enter code here`00:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.359 (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/main.js:659:70)
at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
at webpackJsonpCallback (http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
at http://192.168.43.66:8100/build/main.js:1:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by running

```
npm i core-js
```